# Create 3x3 matplotlib subplot but with plots missing at certain locations

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I had 6 plots I wanted to arrange into a subplot setup in the usual way (plt.subplots etc.).

However for visualisation reasons I need them arranged in the following way:

```
|1 0 0 |

|1 1 0 |

|1 1 1 |
```

Where 1 indicates I want a plot there and 0 indicates I do not. Im not completely sure how I do this with subplots in matplotlib. Any suggestions would be great - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Figure.add_gridspec`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html) and `Figure.add_subplot`

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
>>> gs = fig.add_gridspec(3, 3)
>>> axes = [fig.add_subplot(gs[x,y])
                for x in range(3) for y in range(3) if x >= y]
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could fill in blank subplots on the spots that you want to leave blank, like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

fig, ((ax1, ax2, ax3), (ax4, ax5, ax6), (ax7, ax8, ax9)) = plt.subplots(3, 3)
fig.suptitle('Sharing x per column, y per row')
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.axis("off")
ax3.axis("off")
ax4.plot(x, -y, 'tab:green')
ax5.plot(x, -y**2, 'tab:red')
ax6.axis("off")
ax7.plot(x, -y, 'tab:green')
ax8.plot(x, -y**2, 'tab:red')
ax9.plot(x, -y**2, 'tab:red')
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XykxF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create 3x3 subplots and make the axes of some invisible:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,3)
fig.tight_layout(pad=2.0)
axs[0,1].axis('off')
axs[0,2].axis('off')
axs[1,2].axis('off')
```

Output:
[image: Final Plot]